# How to delete the api displayed images while I'm trying to search for the new one?

Tags: javascript, function, api, axios

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TV Show Search</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TV Show Search</h1>
    <form id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="TV Show title" name="query">
        <button>Search</button>

    </form>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[The result of displayed image in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn266.jpg)

The below code is searching the picture element data in api and it will display the picture after searching it, My goal is while the first searched picture displayed and when i'm trying to search for the different element the previous displayed picture should be deleted. Right now when i search it prints from where the last picture displayed in the browser.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#searchForm');
const input = document.querySelector('.name');

form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = form.elements.query.value;
    const config = {params: {q: searchTerm}}
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows`, config)
    form.elements.query.value = ''
    // console.log(res.data[0].show.image.medium);
    // form.elements.query.value = '';
    // const img = document.createElement('IMG');
    // img.src = res.data[0].show.image.medium;
    // document.body.append(img)
    makeImages(res.data)
})

const makeImages = (shows) => {
    for(let result of shows){
        if(result.show.image) {
            const img = document.createElement('IMG');
            img.src = result.show.image.medium;
            document.body.append(img);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new container for images.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TV Show Search</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TV Show Search</h1>
    <form id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="TV Show title" name="query">
        <button>Search</button>

    </form>
    <div id="results-container"></div><!-- new container -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the first thing you should do in makeImages is clear all the children inside the container.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#searchForm');
const input = document.querySelector('.name');

form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = form.elements.query.value;
    const config = {params: {q: searchTerm}}
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows`, config)
    form.elements.query.value = ''
    // console.log(res.data[0].show.image.medium);
    // form.elements.query.value = '';
    // const img = document.createElement('IMG');
    // img.src = res.data[0].show.image.medium;
    // document.body.append(img)
    makeImages(res.data)
})

const makeImages = (shows) => {
    let container = document.querySelector('#results-container');
    container.empty(); // remove all previous images
    for(let result of shows){
        if(result.show.image) {
            const img = document.createElement('IMG');
            img.src = result.show.image.medium;
            container.append(img); // add images to the container instead of adding them directly to the body.
        }
    }
}
```